# To query from different tables and us it in json object

Tags: json, laravel, backend

I want to get total number of students, and per gender from  each school which every school is correspond to a certain ward_id which will be selected by the user and also to get total number of schools per each ward_id passed through the api request

api url is
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getSchools/{ward_id}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getSchools/%7Bward_id%7D)
code is below

```
public function getSchoolsinWard($id){
  //this will be the id of ward
        $array_count = [];
        $array_school = [];
        $schools = School::where('ward_id', $id)->get();
        
        foreach($schools as $school){
        $array_school[] = $school;
         $data = count($school->grades);
         foreach($school->grades as $grade){
             $total = count($grade->streams);
             foreach($grade->streams as $stream){
                 $total_students = count($stream->students);
                 foreach($stream->students as $student){
                    $array_count[] = $student;
                    $boys = Student::where('id', $student->id)->where('gender', 'male')->get();
                    $total_boys = $boys->count();
                    $girls = Student::where('id', $student->id)->where('gender', 'female')->get();
                    $total_girls = $girls->count();
                 }
             }
         }
        }
 
        $schoolsTotal = School::where('ward_id',$id)->count();
        return response(['message' => 'schools in wards', 
                'schools'=>$array_school,
                'total students'=> $array_count, 
                'total boys'=>$total_boys,
                'total girls' => $total_girls,
                'totals schools' => $schoolsTotal]);
      
    }
```

the code above gives me this postman response

```
    {
       "message":"schools in wards",
       "schools":[
          {
             "id":1,
             "name":"Mivinjeni",
             "educationLevel":"Secondary",
             "ward_id":1,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z",
             "grades":[
                {
                   "id":1,
                   "name":"Form 5",
                   "school_id":1,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:47:34.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:47:34.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      {
                         "id":1,
                         "name":"A",
                         "grade_id":1,
                         "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:38.000000Z",
                         "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:38.000000Z",
                         "students":[
                            {
                               "id":1,
                               "student_name":"Matumbu Mawe",
                               "gender":"male",
                               "stream_id":1,
                               "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:03.000000Z",
                               "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:03.000000Z"
                            },
                            {
                               "id":2,
                               "student_name":"Lukaku Maguire",
                               "gender":"male",
                               "stream_id":1,
                               "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:46.000000Z",
                               "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:46.000000Z"
                            }
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "id":2,
                         "name":"B",
                         "grade_id":1,
                         "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:46.000000Z",
                         "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:46.000000Z",
                         "students":[
                            
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":2,
                   "name":"Form 6",
                   "school_id":1,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:47:59.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:47:59.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      {
                         "id":3,
                         "name":"A",
                         "grade_id":2,
                         "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:52.000000Z",
                         "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:52.000000Z",
                         "students":[
                            
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "id":4,
                         "name":"B",
                         "grade_id":2,
                         "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:56.000000Z",
                         "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:54:56.000000Z",
                         "students":[
                            
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":3,
                   "name":"Form 1",
                   "school_id":1,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:49:41.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:49:41.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      {
                         "id":5,
                         "name":"A",
                         "grade_id":3,
                         "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:55:05.000000Z",
                         "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:55:05.000000Z",
                         "students":[
                            
                         ]
                      },
                      {
                         "id":6,
                         "name":"B",
                         "grade_id":3,
                         "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:55:09.000000Z",
                         "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:55:09.000000Z",
                         "students":[
                            
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":4,
                   "name":"Form 2",
                   "school_id":1,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:49:49.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:49:49.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":5,
                   "name":"Form 3",
                   "school_id":1,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:49:53.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:49:53.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":6,
                   "name":"Form 4",
                   "school_id":1,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:01.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:01.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":2,
             "name":"Miburani",
             "educationLevel":"Secondary",
             "ward_id":1,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:50.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:50.000000Z",
             "grades":[
                {
                   "id":7,
                   "name":"Form 4",
                   "school_id":2,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:10.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:10.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":8,
                   "name":"Form 1",
                   "school_id":2,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:14.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:14.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":9,
                   "name":"Form 2",
                   "school_id":2,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:17.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:17.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "id":10,
                   "name":"Form 3",
                   "school_id":2,
                   "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:19.000000Z",
                   "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:50:19.000000Z",
                   "streams":[
                      
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "total students":[
          {
             "id":1,
             "student_name":"Matumbu Mawe",
             "gender":"male",
             "stream_id":1,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:03.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:03.000000Z"
          },
          {
             "id":2,
             "student_name":"Lukaku Maguire",
             "gender":"male",
             "stream_id":1,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:46.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:58:46.000000Z"
          },
          {
             "id":3,
             "student_name":"Mary Mzuri",
             "gender":"female",
             "stream_id":1,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T15:09:15.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T15:09:15.000000Z"
          },
          {
             "id":4,
             "student_name":"Anna Crush",
             "gender":"female",
             "stream_id":1,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T15:09:24.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T15:09:24.000000Z"
          }
       ],
       "total boys":0,
       "total girls":1,
       "totals schools":2
    }
```

but what I wanted as the postman request is this below

```
    {
       "message":"schools in wards",
       "schools":[
          {
             "id":1,
             "name":"Mivinjeni",
             "educationLevel":"Secondary",
             "ward_id":1,
             "total_students":21,
             "total_boys":11,
             "total_girls":10,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z"
          },
          {
             "id":1,
             "name":"Mivinjeni",
             "educationLevel":"Secondary",
             "ward_id":1,
             "total_students":21,
             "total_boys":11,
             "total_girls":10,
             "created_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z",
             "updated_at":"2022-06-04T14:41:34.000000Z"
          }
       ],
       "total_students_in_wards":42,
       "total_schools":2
    }
```

the relation  between models is  Ward hasMany School hasMany Grades hasMany Stream hasMany Students

Comment: So where's your problem? This is not a question, you simply told us what you want to do.

Comment: I want to get the second postman request because is where i have got a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of subquery selects to get the counts for **total_students**, **total_boys**, **total_girls**. Then for the **total_students_in_ward** and **total_schools** you can use Collection's **sum** and **count** methods - there's no need for a separate query for the count.

```php
public function getSchoolsinWard($id)
{
    $schools = School::query()
        ->where('ward_id',$id)
        ->addSelect([
            'total_students' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereIn(
                    'stream_id', 
                    Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
                        'grade_id',
                        Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
                    )
                ),
      
            'total_boys' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereRaw('gender = "male"')
                ->whereIn(
                    'stream_id', 
                    Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
                        'grade_id',
                        Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
                    )
                ),
      
            'total_girls' => Student::selectRaw('count(*)')
                ->whereRaw('gender = "female"')
                ->whereIn(
                    'stream_id', 
                    Stream::select('id')->whereIn(
                        'grade_id',
                        Grade::select('id')->whereColumn('school_id', 'schools.id')
                    )
                )      
        ])->get();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'schools in wards',
        'schools' => $schools,
        'total_students_in_ward' => $schools->sum('total_students'),
        'total_schools' => $schools->count()
    ]);
}
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Subquery Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#subquery-selects)

[Laravel Docs - Collections - Method Sum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sum)

[Laravel Docs - Collections - Method Count](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-count)

Comment: Yes @Donkarnash it worked very well, what is this? approach is this query builder approach?

Comment: @deo_gemini This is very much an Eloquent way (look at the docs link for subquery selects it's under Eloquent)  which also works with query builder approach. Subqueries allow you to run nested queries within another database query.